# Haystack and whoosh index size

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm using django haystack + whoosh as search backend.

When i run index update it simple creating new index file with same size and index grow very fast (let's say my content changing fast and i want to keep index fresh and updating it every 5-10 mins).

So is that behavior desirable? Can i reduce index size? Maybe whoosh can not stupidly make new full index file but use some deltas to keep index smaller?

Answer (score 0):

I know Whoosh provides an IndexWriter object that can be used to add a certain file to the index, without having to re-index everything, but I'm not sure how to make it work with Haystack. Perhaps something like

```
from haystack import site
site.get_index(model).update_object(instance)
```

Comment: That's not an option for me. Looks like it's easier to recreate index each time with --noinput option and when the volumes of data will grew much just change whoosh to xapian or solr.